# Adding custom font to ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, fonts, ckeditor

I am trying to add a custom font to "ckeditor".

I have this font file in project folder `FRUTIG_0` and i am trying to add it to "ckeditor".

Add it it to the drop-down was pretty easy:

I added to "config.js":

```
config.contentsCss = 'StyleSheet1.css'
config.font_names = 'FRUTIG_0;'
```

StyleSheet1.css contains:

```
@font-face {  
       font-family: "FRUTIG_0"; 
    font-family: "FRUTIG_0"; /* font name for the feature use*/
    src: url(FRUTIGERLTSTD-BLACKCN_0.otf); /* IE */  
    src: local("FRUTIG_0"), url("FRUTIG_0.otf") format("OpenType"); /*non-IE*/  
}
```

`FRUTIG_0` appears in drop-down, but it's not styled as the font styling and
if i coose it it's not appear that anthing happens,

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: not sure if this was the thing that made it work but, i changed `OpenType` to `opentype` and it worked

Answer (score -3):

i have find how to ;)

Just need to add de @face properties to the CSS of the html/php files too ;)